# How to update info that has been displayed with a while loop?

Tags: php

So on my website, I have displayed a while loop that has checkboxes

```
<?php
$data = "SELECT * FROM category";
$dataResult = $conn->query($data);
if ($dataResult && $dataResult->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $dataResult->fetch_assoc()){
        $currency = $row['category'];
        $option = $row['options'];
       if ($option == 1) {
            $checkbox = "checked";
          }else {
            $checkbox = "";
          }
        echo"<input class='form-check-input' $checkbox type='checkbox' name='$currency' value='$option'>
          <label for=''>$currency</label></br>";} } ?>
```

Now I want to create an update function that changes the value of the options in db either 1(true) or 0(false) so this is what I tried but failed.

```
<?php
              if (isset($_POST['updateCurrency'])) {
                $data = "SELECT * FROM category";
                $dataResult = $conn->query($data);
                if ($dataResult && $dataResult->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $dataResult->fetch_assoc()){
                $currency = $row['category'];
                $option = $row['options'];

                $curr = $_POST[$currency];
                $option = $_POST[$option];

                $sql ="UPDATE categoty SET category='$currency' options='$option'";
                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                header("Location: ../admin/admin-list-settings.php?data=updated");
                }else{
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
                }
                }
              }
            }
            ?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the possibility to add new categories but also be able to disable them by changing their value via a checkbox. Here is the table setup

```
 CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `options` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hi Roberts,
The table structure is not in Normalized form. So You will get error on progress.
So Create a option table separately and store it's value in the category table.
Then it will be better.

Comment: Hi Roberts, what is the specific problem, how does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: You are not using `$curr` therefore `currency` is always set to `$currency` thus it isn't changed. Additionally, you set **each row** to the same `$option` value. Is that really what you're trying to achive?